# Часть "авто" в словах "автомобиль" и "автодорога"?

Tags: словообразование, морфемика, морфемный-разбор

В слове *автомобиль* читается иностранная приставка *авто-* греческого происхождения (др.-греч. αὐτός «сам, он»). В современном русском языке эту часть слова *автомобиль* принято относить либо к корневым морфемам, либо к префиксоидам — пограничной области между приставкой и корнем.

Слово *автодорога* является сложносокращённым от словосочетания *автомобильная дорога* и в нём часть *авто* принято называть "начальной частью сложного слова":

> АВТО... — начальная часть сложных слов, вносящая значение слова: автомобиль, автомобильный. *(Словарь Т.Ф. Ефремовой)*
>
> АВТО…1 Первая составная часть сложных слов, соответствующая по значению: 1) слову автомобильный; 2) слову автомобиль. *(Малый академический словарь)*

Хочется разобраться, чем являются части *авто* в словах *автомобиль* и *автодорога* с точки зрения морфемики: чем-то схожим, но имеющим разную соотнесённость, либо же это принципиально разные явления?

Comment: А как же "автономный", "автократия"? Авто -  сам.

Answer (score 1):

> Хочется разобраться, чем являются части авто в словах автомобиль и
>   автодорога с точки зрения морфемики: чем-то схожим, но имеющим разную
>   соотнесённость, либо же это принципиально разные явления?

Хороший вопрос на самом деле, хотя не очень понятно, что означает тут слово "соотнесенность".

Не имею возможности аргументировать с академической чистотой, но полагаю, что это действительно разные явления. Речь, понятно, о морфемном составе в рамках русского, а не языка-источника (или языков).

Я полагаю так. "Автомобиль" не подлежит в русском языке морфемному разложению, это так сказать "цельнозаимствованное" слово. Хотя в нем просматривается две заимствованные (исходно - латинские) основы, соединение их в одно понятие произошло не в русском, слово появилось в таком виде в европейских языках (французском, вернее всего) и уже в таком соединенном виде мигрировало на русскую почву. В таких случаях морфемное членение обычно не проводят. Сравните с популярным сейчас "коронавирус" или чуть более ранним Беларусь - в обоих на первый взгляд просматриваются две очевидные основы, но морфемно это не сложные слова (иначе по правилам русского языка писались бы через *о*).

Со словом "автодорога" ситуация иная. Вторая основа ("дорога") здесь, очевидно, русская, соединение в единое понятие не могло произойти вне русского языка. Поэтому при морфемном анализе без разложения на два корневых морфа не обойтись.

Вынужденно писал кратко, даже конспективно, но, надеюсь, смысл донес.